# C++ can anyone think of a more efficient and faster way to calculate products of a string?

Tags: python, c++, performance, cartesian-product

I'm trying to write a zip file brute forcer. I wrote it in python but moved to c++ to make it faster. To be honest, I'm really inexperienced in c++ so I'm sorry of any of this code is an abomination.
What I'm trying to recreate is python's `itertools.product` for a string of length k
example of of output would be

```
string = "az"
repeat = 3
for i in product(string,repeat=repeat):
    print(i)

#output
#aaa
#aaz
#aza
etc etc....
```

Here is how fast PyPy is compared to c++ code.

PyPy time: 6.7s

C++ time: 19s

PYTHON CODE

```
from itertools import *
from time import *

def prodgen(string, repeat):
    yield from product(string,repeat=repeat)

string="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
repeat=6
start=perf_counter()
for i in prodgen(string,repeat = repeat):
    #print(i)
    pass
print(perf_counter()-start)
```

C++ CODE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include<array>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

unsigned long int intpow(int mantisa, int exponent) {
    unsigned long int retval = mantisa;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent - 1; i++) {
        retval = retval * mantisa;
    }
    return retval;
}

void product(string& str, int repeat) {
    int base, i;
    unsigned long int nocombinations, quotient,n;
    const char* vecstring = str.c_str(); //converting input to character array as it is faster to index

    string outputstring;   //This will be the string that the function "yields" (I don't know how to yield in c++) 
    base = str.size();  //This will be the "base" we count in 
    nocombinations = intpow(base, repeat);    //The number of combinations we need to iterate through

    char* outputchararray = new char[repeat];       //Making an empty character array which ultimately gets converted to outputstring later. (faster than indexing a string for some reason)
    //now this is just countinng in "base n"
    for (n = 0; n < nocombinations; n++) {
        quotient = n;                   //cant modify n like we can in python so we need to make a copy       
        for (i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            outputchararray[i] = vecstring[quotient % base];
            quotient = quotient /  base;
        }
        outputstring.assign(outputchararray, repeat);     //Now converting the character array back to string to "yield return?" 
        //cout << outputstring << endl;
        //yield return outputstring;    //How do I do this in c++?
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int size =6;
    std::clock_t    start;
    cout << "starting" << endl;
    start = std::clock();
    product(str, size);
    cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

So yeah PyPy ends up doing it 12 seconds faster. I was hoping c++ would be a few hundred times faster.
I'm sure the algorithm isn't optimized and that I have thought of a really bad way of doing this.
You guys got a more efficient way in your mind? Been pulling my hair out for days.

Comment: I would suggest using the chrono library to do an improved benchmarking

Comment: Do you have optimizations enabled?

Comment: That's 1,853,494,656 iterations, copying six characters each time. Counting one nanosecond per character – which is optimistic, given the two divisions – gives an approximate lower boundary of 11.12 seconds.

Comment: I hope I am not teaching you anything new but the itertools module is written in C so you probably can't squeeze a lot of performance out of it anyway. Your code looks fine to me: with optimizations enabled it runs in 7.4 seconds on my machine. What optimization flags are you using ?

Comment: and once the algorithm is optimized, the next step is to use SIMD to make it even faster

Comment: The other next step might be to split up the calculation so you can run it on multiple threads/cores at once.  It does seem to be an embarrassingly-parallel problem.

Comment: Zip file brute forcer - does it mean, you want to decrypt a zipfile? Most probably, each step to try to decrypt with a given password will take a magnitude longer, than to generate the next password candidate, so it is not reasonable, to optimize the pwd-generation.

Comment: "converting input to character array as it is faster to index" -- if you can really measure this, it might indicate that you are either not using the compiler's optimizer or that you are using its "safe STL" or "diagnostic mode", which sprinkles checks against what would normally be undefined behaviour. Of course, those checks take time. That said, your question is rather open-ended, perhaps more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com. Still, if you want to optimize things, you have to measure your progress and should profile the code. Both are complex topics on their own.